# I need to use a file to update/get High Score information

Tags: java, file

Please help. I am trying to make the program access a file named "highscore.txt", then:

1: Write a new number in the file

2: Get the lowest value of a list of numbers in the file.

Please post the code if you know how.

*****Note: I am new to Java so I barely know how to even access the file*****

Edit:

I got code that I believe should work, but when I run the program it says

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
        at game.game.main(game.java:91)
    Java Result: 1
```

Here is line 84 - 94, and the code I got.

```
    84: Writer wr = new FileWriter("highscore.txt");
    85:            wr.write(tries);
    86:            wr.close();
    87:            lowest = tries;
    88:            File file = new File("highscore.txt");
    89: Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    90: while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    91:    numb = inputFile.nextDouble();
    92:    if (numb < lowest) lowest = number;
    93: }
    94: inputFile.close();
```

Edit:

I have it somewhat working. There is an error and it is that it just puts a random Unicode symbol in the text file.
Here is the code for that part:

```
    try {

        int content = tries;

        File file = new File("highscore.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                Writer wr = new FileWriter("highscore.txt");
                wr.write(tries);
                wr.close();
                lowest = tries;
                File file = new File("highscore.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        numb = inputFile.nextInt();
        if (numb < lowest) lowest = numb;
    }
```

File:

```
    32
    12
    7
    9
    18
    66
    13
    17
    91
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your file when asking a question about how to read said file

Comment: Looks like you're trying to stuff a non-double into a double. [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
        int tries = 8;
    // Writing to the file
    try {
        int content = tries;

        File file = new File("highscore.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        pw.println(content);
        pw.close();
        /*
         * FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
         * BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); bw.write(content);
         * bw.close();
         */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
     * Writer wr; try { wr = new FileWriter("highscore.txt");
     * wr.write(tries); wr.close(); } catch (Exception e) {
     * 
     * }
     */

    // Getting the minimum score from the file
    int lowest = tries;
    File file = new File("highscore.txt");
    Scanner inputFile;
    try {
        inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
            int numb = inputFile.nextInt();
            if (numb < lowest)
                lowest = numb;
        }
        System.out.println("lowest Score is: " + lowest);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```